# Conditionally remove calls to a function in AS3, like C#'s ConditionalAttribute

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

At work we have a lot of AS3 code that conditionally performs logging or assertions like so:

```
CONFIG::debug
{
    assert(blah > 2);
}
```

I would really rather just write:

```
assert(blah > 2);
```

And have the definition of `assert()` specify that in release mode, any calls to it, **and the expressions for its arguments**, should not be evaluated -- that is, it should be as if the line was empty. Not only should `assert()` never be called in release, but the condition `blah > 2` itself should not be evaluated.

In C# this would look like:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void assert(...) { ... }
```

or, in C++ (roughly):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define assert(cond) if(!(cond)) { explode(); }
#else
    #define assert(cond) /* nothing */
#endif
```

Is there any way to do something similar in AS3, or do we have to do the conditional compilation blocks around everything? I have been looking around manuals but have found nothing useful yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to make the flex compiler ignore all calls to a function by annotating its declaration like that.  In fact, I'd be very interested if you ever find a way to do this - it would help to clean up the source code of my projects quite a bit...

You could specify two versions of a method, as described in [this example](http://www.pixelate.de/blog/debug-and-release-builds-with-as3-conditional-compilation).  So you could have a fully functional `assert(...args)` in your debug version, and an empty one in the release version, but you'd still have the function calls and argument evaluations in the byte code. :(

Comment: +1 I'll confirm this is not possible. Nice feature though! You should submit as feature request to Adobe's Jira.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do this.

If you use the `-omit-trace-statements` flex compiler flag(automatically enabled in release builds), then all calls to the `trace` function will be stripped out completely, including evaluation of their arguments.

So simply wrap your assert call in a call to trace:

```
trace(assert(blah > 2));
```

You can verify that this works correctly by doing a test with some side-effects inside your `assert`.

Answer (score 0):

The `-omit-trace-statements` advice no longer works with recent SDKs. According to [Flex 4.6 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html), all it does now is: *Enables trace() statements from being written to the flashlog.txt file.*
I guess *enables* is a typo, what is meant is *prevents*.

You can test it with this code, for example:

```
var err:Error;
trace(err = new Error('trace() arguments are still being evaluated.'));
if (err != null)
    throw err;
```

I tried hard to accomplish what the OP wanted, but so far haven't found a better solution. AS3 doesn't have support for macros, and conditional compilation can get rid of asserts body, but not the arguments evaluation.
Short of using a preprocessor (e.g. asserts stripper), the rather ugly syntax seems to be the only choice:

```
CONFIG::debug { assertTrue(fontDescription != null, 'fontDescription != null'); }
```